# Added 'search function' using React-admin package, but not working, why?

Tags: filter, full-text-search, react-admin, textinput, npm-package

I am using React-admin to create a customer dashboard where they can find their invoices for all months. Now I would like to add search function to this so that customers can search invoices according to any field,say entity_name.
I am able to add search element on ui, but its not working.

I added search functionality by importing {Filter, TextInput} from React-admin. And I am using data from "ra-data-simple-rest"; and running sever on port 5000 in my local machine.

Here is my code:

```
const InvoiceFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput source="entity_name" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
);
const InvoiceList = (props) => {
  return (
    <List {...props} filters={<InvoiceFilter />}>
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="entity_name" />
        <DateField source="period_start" />
        <DateField source="period_end" />
        <TextField source="total" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper components for the filter function.
the filters props is for FilterForm

```
<FilterForm filters={postFilters} />
```

Placing the filters props in List component is not doing anything.
Create proper filter and pass it to a proper component like shown in the documentation [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilterButton.html)

Comment: Thanks Arbin. I used FilterForm as you suggested in the documentation, I got search bar UI but still not working.

Comment: The InvoiceFilter Function you created is not a proper filter, have you changed this as well?

Comment: Yes, I also changed InvoiceFilter function as: const InvoiceFilter = [<TextInput source="entity_name" alwaysOn />];

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filters-filter-inputs), you could try:

```
const invoiceFilters = [
  <TextInput source="entity_name" alwaysOn />
);

const InvoiceList = () => {
  return (
    <List filters={invoiceFilters}>
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="entity_name" />
        <DateField source="period_start" />
        <DateField source="period_end" />
        <TextField source="total" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```